# How to add a shortcut to mobile homescreen in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: forms, mobile, xamarin, xamarin.forms, homescreen

How can I add a shortcut icon to mobile homescreen in Xamarin.Forms ?

I am a beginner in Xamarin and try to do this.

Edit:

Currently I don't have attached an Mac for IOS, yet
so what I want is to run only Droid for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deploy your Android application via the Android play store, the shortcut will be added to the home screen automatically. 
For iOS, it should get added by default when you install the app.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following attribute to your `Activity`-class:

```
[Activity (MainLauncher=true)]
public class MainActivity: FormsApplicationActivity {
  // ...
}
```

That should be all. For iOS there is no special action required.

Comment: I got it, I should then add the usual C# code to this core method inside the brackets. This is great.

Comment: Yes I will add just add a Response.Redirect("myurl"); and that's what I need in fact, belonging to @wishmaster's post.

Comment: Excuse me, did you write this for native or for forms ?

Comment: This example is for forms. There is only a minor difference if you want to use it for a native approach (the base class of MainActivity).

Comment: I couldn't run. Could you write step by step? I need just a blank forms application (currently only for Android). I create a blank forms application but when I debug it, it gets 1400+ errors (I don't have add the Portable Class Library, Is 1400+ errors because of the lack of this ?)

Comment: I don't understand how the initial question relates to the 1400+ errors. Propably you included a wrong version of the Support Library. It's a good idea to create another question and don't forget to include the referenced versions of Xamarin.Forms and other NuGet-Packages.